# XML ignore attribute

Tags: deserialization

I want to set [XmlIgnore] attribute on class because I want it to be skipped in deserialization, but I want to keep its children to be deserialized.

is it possible to do so?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It makes no sense to want to deserialise children of an attribute you have not deserialised.  There is nowhere for them to go - it's a bit like saying I want to create the properties of a class but not the class itself.

If you really wanted to do this I think you would have to write your own XML parser and then find somewhere to stick them - doesn't make sense to me.